# Sending form data to an email after a successful submission using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am trying to make a simple page where users will request for some services they would like to have. After passing the validation I save the form data into a database. This program should also send an email notification when someone ask for some services. So, Until this my code is working.

But I want to get the form data in the email body/message when a form is successfully submited but so far I could not manage to do it. I googled and tried some but did not work.

How can I do it using codeigniter? Could someone guide me how can I fix this? If you need full HTML code please let me know. I would appreciate your help.

**Contact.php file (Controller)**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Contact extends CI_Controller {


function __construct() 
{

    parent::__construct();

    //load the contact_model
    $this->load->model('contact_model');

}


public function index()
{

     //load view pages 
     $this->load->view('Template/header');
     $this->load->view('contact');
     $this->load->view('Template/footer');  

}


public function validate_form()
{

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

    //FORM VALIDATION

    //First Name
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[17]');

    //Last Name 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[17]');

    //User Name
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'trim|required|alpha|strtolower|min_length[3]');


    //Email
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');

    //Manager's Full Name
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('m_name', 'Full Name', 'trim|required');

    //Comment 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'Comment', 'trim|required');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)

            {

                //echo validation_errors();
                $this->load->view('Template/header');
                $this->load->view('contact');
                $this->load->view('Template/footer');

                //$redirect = $this->input->post('url');
                //$this->session->set_flashdata('errors',validation_errors());     
            }

            else
            {

                $specialised_category =  $this->input->post('checkbox_cat');

                $data = array(

                'f_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'l_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                'user_name' => $this->input->post('user_name'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'fullname' => $this->input->post('m_name'),
                'comment' => $this->input->post('comment'),
                'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
                 //encoding to JSON and comma sepated values
                'services_list' => json_encode(implode(",", $specialised_category))

                );

                //inserting data  
                //$this->db->insert('sysops_tbl', $data);
                $this->contact_model->insert_into_db($data);

                //load the form success message once submitted correctly
                $this->load->view('formsuccess');

                $this->send($data);

                //redirect to the main page
                //redirect(base_url());

            }

    }


public function send($value='')

{
    //load the email library
    $this->load->library('email');

    //Sending email 
                $config_email = array(
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'charset' =>'iso-8859-1',
                'wordwrap' => TRUE
                );
                //debug
                //print_r($value);

                //override the config from text to html
                $this->email->initialize($config_email);

                //printing manager email and name
                $this->email->from($this->input->post('email'),$this->input->post('m_name'));
                //receipant email

                $this->email->to('xxx.xx@xxx.com');
                //header
                //$this->email->set_header(json_encode(implode(",", $this->input->post('checkbox_cat'))),'binded');
                //email subject
                $this->email->subject('We need user access for');
                //want to inject values here in the email message
                $this->email->message('Check above !!:');
                //print the message if email is sent 
                if($this->email->send())
                {
                    return TRUE;
                    //echo "Email is sent";
                }else
                {
                    return FALSE;
                    //echo $this->email->print_debugger();
                }

}

}
?>
```

**for check boxes partial code is given**

**contact.php (views)**

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Which ?</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">


                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_cat[]" class="get_value" value="option4" /> option4
                            </label>

                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_cat[]" class="get_value" value="option5" /> option5
                            </label>

                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_cat[]" class="get_value" value="option6" /> option6
                            </label>

                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_cat[]" class="get_value" value="option7" /> option7
                            </label>

                        </div>
</div>
```

**contact_model.php (model)**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class contact_model extends CI_Model
{

function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function insert_into_db($data)
{
    // Inserting into database table
    $this->db->insert('sysops_tbl', $data);
} 

}

?>
```

Comment: you are not sending data in $this->send();  use  $this->send($data); so data will be in $value (parameter of send function) than you can fetch it from $value and send in mail content

Comment: I will give a try and update you. Thanks

Comment: @hrishi, According to your tips I tried and now my question is that how can I inject those values in email message body and a normal foreach loop seems not work in controller. I updated the code.

Comment: Can you update code in question. You can pass values in message. If you want to send well designed template in mail then create view with all values and then pass that view to as message part.                                                         $msg = $this->load->view('email_template','',true);                              $this->email->message($msg);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function send($value='')
{
    //load the email library
    $this->load->library('email');

    //Sending email 
    $config_email = array(
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset' =>'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $msg = $this->load->view('email_template',$value,true);

    //override the config from text to html
    $this->email->initialize($config_email);

    //printing manager email and name
    $this->email->from($this->input->post('email'),$this->input->post('m_name'));
    //receipant email

    $this->email->to('xxx.xx@xxx.com');
    //header
    //$this->email->set_header(json_encode(implode(",", $this->input->post('checkbox_cat'))),'binded');
    //email subject
    $this->email->subject('We need user access for');
    $this->email->message($msg);
    //print the message if email is sent 
    if($this->email->send())
    {
        return TRUE;
        //echo "Email is sent";
    }else
    {
        return FALSE;
        //echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }

}
```

email_template : Design it as you required

```
<html>
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <?php echo $f_name." ".$l_name;  ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Comment</label>
        <?php echo $comment;  ?>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: I used one of my gmail account and was able to receive email once.Have not changed anything other than the email_template.php file (adding some more values like city and so on and it worked). Now I do not receive any emails anymore and I have no errors in the code.And its bit strange.